# Where is a Windows desktop spinner info?

Tags: windows, animated-gif

I installed an application (don't remember which one) and it left a spinner (I assume it's an animated GIF) in the middle of my desktop that I can't remove.

I have logged out, rebooted, changed my desktop theme, etc to no avail.

[image: the spinner image]

Would information about that image be kept somewhere so I can go in and remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could just be a normal window (windows can be partially-transparent and not respond to clicks). [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has a tool where you can point at a window and get the process to which it belongs.

Comment: Aha, finally! That was it - I never considered it was a process.  (Disney Vacation Connection - the stars should have been a hint i guess)  I killed it and it came back when i logged out and back in (it has an application in Startup).  I removed that and it's gone for good.  Thanks!